# iOS - presentModalViewController causes some animation artefacts (iPhone)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitoolbar, presentmodalviewcontroller, uiwindow

I am showing a UIToolbar (with some buttons) as a subview of the current topwindow. This works fine.
At some point I want to show a modal dialog (using presentModalViewController) over the UIToolbar.

I tried to hide it in so many ways (removeFromSuperview, sendSubviewToBack, setHidden, changing frame size to 0 and more) but they all caused some animation side effects when the most common one looks like the UIToolbar almost disappears but still showing some faded buttons on the background.

Trying to solve this for a few days now. Am I doing something wrong or is just a bug?

Thanks :)

Comment: What's your target? As of iOS6 `presentModalViewController` is deprecated. Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` paired with `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` instead and set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

Comment: Thanks! I took your advice and also found some stupid mistake I did. Works perfectly now...

Answer (score 0):

Try hide all buttons on UIToolBar before you hide it, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *toolbarButtons = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];
[toolbarButtons removeAllObjects];
[self setToolbarItems:toolbarButtons animated:NO];
```